Creating an Estimator for the Dimension of Bernoulli-distributed Vectors from Observed pairwise Dot Products
I have I individuals defined by vectors $P_i \sim \mathcal{B}(1,1/2)^d$ iid. We can note $\overline{P}_i = \langle P_i, \textbf{1} \rangle$ the proportion of 1's in individual i; $c_{ij} = \langle P_i, P_j \rangle$ the compatibility between i and j; with $\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{d}\sum_t^d x_t.y_t$.
Suppose I observe all compatibilities white noise near, my problem is to create an estimator of d. I started by,
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{E}(c_{jm}.c_{im}) & = \sum_{k = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P_m} = k) \mathrm{E}(c_{jm}.c_{im} | \overline{P}_m) \\
    & = \sum_{k = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P_m} = k) \mathrm{E}(c_{jm} | \overline{P}_m)\mathrm{E}(c_{im} | \overline{P}_m) \\
    & = \overline{P}_i \overline{P}_j \sum_{k = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P_m} = k) \overline{P}_m^2 \\
    & = \overline{P}_i \overline{P}_j \sum_{k = 0}^d \binom{d}{k} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^d \left( \frac{k}{d} \right)^2 \\
    & = \overline{P}_i \overline{P}_j \frac{1}{d^2} \mathrm{E}[(d.\overline{P})^2] = \overline{P}_i \overline{P}_j \frac{1}{4} (1 + d^{-1})
\end{align}
With $d.c_{ij}|_{d.\overline{P_i} = k_i, d.\overline{P_j} = k_j} \sim \mathcal{B}(\text{min}(k_i, k_j), \text{max}(k_i/d, k_j/d))$. with $\overline{P}_i \leq \overline{P}_j $ we have without loss of generality $\mathrm{P}(d.c_{ij} = k) = \binom{d.\overline{P}_i}{k} (\overline{P}_j)^k ( 1 - \overline{P}_j)^{d.\overline{P}_i - k}$. $k$ the number of 1 in $P_i$ that match a 1 in $P_j$ with a probability $\overline{P}_j$, and $d.\overline{P}_i - k$ the number of 1 in $P_i$ that match a 0 in $P_j$. Then, $\mathrm{E}[c_{ij}|_{\overline{P}_i,\overline{P}_j}] = \overline{P}_i\overline{P}_j$. I think it allows us to move from the second to the third line.
And with $d.\overline{P} \sim \mathcal{B}(d,1/2)$ for the last line. $\mathrm{E}[(d.\overline{P})^2] = d/4 + d^2/4$ thus $\mathrm{E}[\overline{P}^2] = \frac{1}{4}(1 + d^{-1})$.
As I can estimate in the data both $c_{jm}.c_{im}$ and the proportion $\overline{P}$ I thought it would be easy to reuse the expectation of $c_{jm}.c_{im}$ to create an estimator of d, so I used T defined below, the results on simulations are convincing but I can't see how to calculate $\mathrm{E}(T)$ as the numerator and denominator are not independent.
$T = \frac{1}{\binom{I}{2}}\sum_{i<j}^I \left[ \left( \frac{1}{I-2}\sum_{k \neq i,j}^I c_{ik} c_{jk}\right) / \left( \frac{4}{I^2} \sum_{k \neq i}^I c_{ik} \sum_{k \neq j}^I c_{jk} \right) \right]$ then my estimator of d is simply $(4*T - 1)^{-1}$.
I used the fact that $d.c_{ij}|_{d.\overline{P_i} = k} \sim \mathcal{B}(k,1/2)$ such that I can estimate $\overline{P_i}$ as 2 time the mean compatibility of the individual i.
If you've spotted any errors and help me compute $\mathrm{E}(T)$, I'd love to hear from you! Thank you very much,

\begin{align*}
    T' = \frac{I-2}{\binom{I}{2}}\sum_{i<j}^I \left[ \sum_{k \neq i,j}^I \left( c_{ik} c_{jk} (\sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im} \sum_{m \neq i,k}^I c_{jm})^{-1} \right) \right]
\end{align*}
With I going to infinity,
\begin{align*}
    & \mathrm{E} \left[ c_{ik} c_{jk} (\sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im} \sum_{m \neq i,k}^I c_{jm})^{-1} | \overline{P}_k, \overline{P}_i, \overline{P}_j \right] \\
   & = \mathrm{E}[c_{ik} | \overline{P}_k, \overline{P}_i] \, \mathrm{E}[c_{jk} | \overline{P}_k, \overline{P}_j] \, \mathrm{E}\left[ \sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im} \sum_{m \neq i,k}^I c_{jm} | \overline{P}_k, \overline{P}_i \right]^{-1} \\
   & = \frac{k_i.k}{d^2} \, \frac{k_j.k}{d^2} \, \frac{4}{(I-2)^2} \, \frac{d^2}{k_i.k_j} = \frac{4}{(I-2)^2} \left( \frac{k}{d} \right)^2 \\
\end{align*}
To go to the second to the third line we need that $\sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im}$ converges toward $(I-2)\mathrm{E}[c_{im}] = \frac{(I-2)}{2}\overline{P}_i$. Iff $I$ BIG (by that i mean huge don't mistake),
\begin{align*}
   & \mathrm{E} \left[ c_{ik} c_{jk} (\sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im} \sum_{m \neq i,k}^I c_{jm})^{-1} \right] \\
   & = \sum_{k = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_k  = k)  \sum_{k_i = 0}^d \sum_{k_j = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_j  = k_j) \, \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_i  = k_i) \, \mathrm{E} \left[ c_{ik} c_{jk} (\sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im} \sum_{m \neq i,k}^I c_{jm})^{-1} | \overline{P}_k, \overline{P}_i, \overline{P}_j \right] \\
   & = \sum_{k = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_k  = k) \,\frac{4}{(I-2)^2} \left( \frac{k}{d} \right)^2 \, \sum_{k_i = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_i  = k_i) \sum_{k_j = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_j  = k_j) \\
   & = \frac{4}{(I-2)^2} \sum_{k = 0}^d \mathrm{P}(d.\overline{P}_k  = k) \left( \frac{k}{d} \right)^2 = \frac{4}{(I-2)^2} \mathrm{E}[(d.\overline{P})^2] = \frac{1 + d^{-1}}{(I-2)^2} 
\end{align*}
Finaly,
\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{E}[T'] & = \frac{I-2}{\binom{I}{2}}\sum_{i<j}^I \sum_{k \neq i,j}^I \mathrm{E} \left[ c_{ik} c_{jk} (\sum_{m \neq j,k}^I c_{im} \sum_{m \neq i,k}^I c_{jm})^{-1} \right] \\
    & = \frac{I-2}{\binom{I}{2}}\sum_{i<j}^I \sum_{k \neq i,j}^I \left( \frac{1 + d^{-1}}{(I-2)^2} \right) = 1 + d^{-1}
\end{align*}
$T = (T' - 1)^{-1}$ we get $\mathrm{E}[T] = d$ BAAM
Any validation ? Thx

Because each compatibility has to be rational, the simplest estimator to me would be the least common multiple (lcm) of all denominators of compatibilities. This, of course, has some negative bias, but I (intuitively) guess it will be consistent.
PS: If data are unfortunately stored in floating point arithmetic, some conversion error to integer arithmetic could also occur, adding an additional source of error beyond the statistical one. But this demonstrates the importance of doing statistics before collecting data.

Nice idea thanks ! Unfortunately, yes, the aim is to apply this method to data with errors.  It's true that I've totally omitted their presence, but since I'm not calculating the variance and it doesn't change the (nose) result...
